# How To Change Value of Selectboxes Based on ID in query

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a few selectbox and i want to change their default options based on an id that i have in query for them .i want this action to keep the selected option on refreshing the whole page. i wrote javascript code but it does not work correctly and in some cases it return wrong or null value for selectboxes.
how can i improve my code to keep selected option after page refreshed ?
here is my code :

```js
document.getElementsByName("continent1")[0].value=[##cms.query.continent1##]
document.getElementsByName("continent2")[0].value=[##cms.query.continent2##]
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<select name="continent1">
  <option value="">First continent</option>
  <option value="123">Asia</option>
  <option value="321">Africa</option>
  <option value="478">America</option>
</select>

<br/>
<br/>

<select name="continent2">
  <option value="">Second continent</option>
  <option value="001">Euroupe</option>
  <option value="002">Australia</option>
  <option value="003">Asisa</option>
</select>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: What does mean _[##cms.query.continent1##]_ ?!!

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Template engine i think

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki i have continent1 in my addressbar . for example continent1=123 in my addressbar

Comment: @inaz can you paste the full URL pls ?

Comment: @SofieneDjebali http://192.168.0.45/list.bc?continent1=123&continent2=003

Comment: Should work if you're getting the right value from the URM : https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/DTcHh/39231/

Comment: @SofieneDjebali url is not my problem i just get value from url. i have problem with selected values

Comment: _i have problem with selected values_ Should just work as the fiddle shows...

Comment: Any errors in the console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the get parameters stored in the url using this code then set your values :

**Javascript**

```
    var options = window.location.search.slice(1)
              .split('&')
              .reduce(function _reduce (/*Object*/ a, /*String*/ b) {
                   b = b.split('=');
                   a[b[0]] = decodeURIComponent(b[1]);
                   return a;
              }, {});

    document.getElementsByName("continent1")[0].value=[options.continent1];
    document.getElementsByName("continent2")[0].value=[options.continent2];
```

Comment: Thank you so much !